# How to add variable error to regex fuzzy search. Python

Tags: python, regex, search, coverage.py

```
import regex,re


sequence = 'aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccc' #being searched
query = 'aaabbbbbbbbbbbbccc' #100% coverage
query_1 = 'aaaabbbbbbbbcbbbcccc' #95% coverage
query_2 = 'aaabbbbcbbbbbcbccc' #90% coverage

threshold = .95
error = len(query_1) - (len(query_1)*threshold) #for query_1 errors must be <= 1

print regex.search(query_1 + '{e<={}}'.format(error),sequence).group(0)
```

Im trying to add additional parameters to a regex search so it only works if a certain percentage of the query is in sequence being searched.

For example, if I wanted it to be at least 95% coverage it would work for `query_1` but it would not work for `query_2`

Comment: The fuzzy matching capabilities of the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `regex` module:

```
import regex
sequence = 'aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccc' #being searched
query = 'aaabbbbbbbbbbbbccc' #100% coverage
query_1 = 'aaaabbbbbbbbcbbbcccc' #95% coverage
query_2 = 'aaabbbbcbbbbbcbccc' #90% coverage
threshold = 0.97
queries = (query, query_1, query_2)
for q in queries:
    error = int(len(q) - (len(q)*threshold))
    m = regex.search(r'(%s){e<=%d}'%(q,error), sequence)
    print 'match' if m else 'nomatch'
```

Comment: what is it called when you add (%s)(%d)%(variable1,variable2) ? i want to look at the documentation because i've seen that before @perreal

Comment: it's called old style string format: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting