# How to find a substring using partial matching

Tags: python, string

```
bigString = "AGAHKGHKHASNHADKRGHFKXXX_I_AM_THERE_XXXXXMHHGRFSAHGSKHASGKHGKHSKGHAK"
smallString = "I_AM_HERE"
```

Which efficient algorithm should I use to find a substring of the "bigString" that matches closely to the "smallString"

```
output = "I_AM_THERE"
```

The output may have few insertions and deletions when compared with small string.

Edit:
Found a good example, very close to my problem here: [How to add variable error to regex fuzzy search. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436761/how-to-add-variable-error-to-regex-fuzzy-search-python)

Comment: Define "matches closely".

Comment: Define "matches closely".

Comment: When you say `that matches closely ` do you mean exact match only or a fuzzy match?

Comment: @ScottHunter Well that's awkward...

Comment: @jazzpi: Great minds not only think alike, but at the same time...

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you mean by "matching closely", nobody can give you a real answer. However, Wikipedia has a nice article on [approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) that describes some of the choices, and links to some of the major algorithms (many of which have links to Python implementations, or at least to easy psuedocode that you can convert to Python). Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Can characters be deleted?  Can characters be inserted?  Can characters be swapped?  Can characters merely be replaced?  Maybe check out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: @dawg,  its not exact. There may be some insertions and deletions

Comment: @dstromberg, actually I was using "Levenshtein" package and the `ratio` and `distance` package is not suitable here

Comment: Take a look at the new [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module

Comment: @dawg, thanks for pointing me to the module. I think it is helpful and can solve my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [almost-ready-to-be-everyones-regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package with fuzzy matching:

```
>>> import regex
>>> bigString = "AGAHKGHKHASNHADKRGHFKXXX_I_AM_THERE_XXXXXMHHGRFSAHGSKHASGKHGKHSKGHAK"
>>> regex.search('(?:I_AM_HERE){e<=1}',bigString).group(0)
'I_AM_THERE'
```

Or:

```
>>> bigString = "AGAH_I_AM_HERE_RGHFKXXX_I_AM_THERE_XXX_I_AM_NOWHERE_EREXXMHHGRFS"
>>> print(regex.findall('I_AM_(?:HERE){e<=3}',bigString))
['I_AM_HERE', 'I_AM_THERE', 'I_AM_NOWHERE']
```

The new regex module will ([hopefully](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0429/)) be part of Python3.4

If you have pip, just type `pip install regex` or `pip3 install regex` until Python 3.4 is out (with regex part of it...)

---

Answer to comment `Is there a way to know the best out of the three in your second example? How to use BESTMATCH flag here?`

Either use the best match flag `(?b)` to get the single best match:

```
print(regex.search(r'(?b)I_AM_(?:ERE){e<=3}', bigString).group(0))
# I_AM_THE
```

Or combine with difflib or take a levenshtein distance with a list of all acceptable matches to the first literal:

```
import regex

def levenshtein(s1,s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1,s2 = s2,s1
    distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
    for index2,char2 in enumerate(s2):
        newDistances = [index2+1]
        for index1,char1 in enumerate(s1):
            if char1 == char2:
                newDistances.append(distances[index1])
            else:
                newDistances.append(1 + min((distances[index1],
                                             distances[index1+1],
                                             newDistances[-1])))
        distances = newDistances
    return distances[-1]

bigString = "AGAH_I_AM_NOWHERE_HERE_RGHFKXXX_I_AM_THERE_XXX_I_AM_HERE_EREXXMHHGRFS"
cl=[(levenshtein(s,'I_AM_HERE'),s) for s in regex.findall('I_AM_(?:HERE){e<=3}',bigString)]

print(cl)
print([t[1] for t in sorted(cl, key=lambda t: t[0])])

print(regex.search(r'(?e)I_AM_(?:ERE){e<=3}', bigString).group(0))
```

Prints:

```
[(3, 'I_AM_NOWHERE'), (1, 'I_AM_THERE'), (0, 'I_AM_HERE')]
['I_AM_HERE', 'I_AM_THERE', 'I_AM_NOWHERE']
```

Comment: @dawg, Thanks. Is there a way to know the best out of the three in your second example? How to use `BESTMATCH` flag here?

Comment: Hi @dawg - this is a great answer. I've edited to reflect how to use the *under-undocumented* BESTMATCH flag `(?b)` instead of the similar but different ENHANCEMATCH flag `(?e)`. Cheers!

Comment: ... [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36818463/how-can-i-find-the-best-fuzzy-string-match) a simple demo of `(?b)` in action.

Comment: @dawg where is the documentation explaining the regex usage? The pypi page and homepage for `regex` does not give working examples of this `{e<=3}` type error/fuzzy syntax. Im trying to find all match candidates above a threshold percentage match. I want the matches and their percentages. So far examples I've found only provide the candidates above a threshold but not the percentages for each candidate

Comment: The documentation for the fuzzy su=yntax is in the [PyPI documentation page](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) for the regex module.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a hacky way to do it with `difflib`:

```
from difflib import *

window = len(smallString) + 1  # allow for longer matches
chunks = [bigString[i:i+window] for i in range(len(bigString)-window)]
get_close_matches(smallString,chunks,1)
```

Output:

```
['_I_AM_THERE']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the dynamic programming problem Longest Common Substring would be of some use here.  Depending on your needs and matching criteria you could perhaps use Longest Common Subseuence