# How can I find the best fuzzy string match?

Tags: python, regex, string, fuzzy-search, pypi-regex

Python's [new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supports fuzzy string matching. Sing praises aloud (now).

Per the docs:

> The `ENHANCEMATCH` flag makes fuzzy matching attempt to improve the fit
>   of the next match that it finds.
>
> The `BESTMATCH` flag makes fuzzy matching search for the best match
>   instead of the next match

The `ENHANCEMATCH` flag is set using `(?e)` as in

> `regex.search("(?e)(dog){e<=1}", "cat and dog")[1]` returns "dog"

but there's nothing on actually setting the `BESTMATCH` flag. How's it done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) on the `BESTMATCH` flag functionality is partial (but improving). Poke-n-hope shows that `BESTMATCH` is set using `(?b)`.

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.search(r"(?e)(?:hello){e<=4}", "What did you say, oh - hello")[0]
'hat d'
>>> regex.search(r"(?b)(?:hello){e<=4}", "What did you say, oh - hello")[0]
'hello'
```